# How to kill a script running in terminal, without closing terminal (Ctrl + C doesn't work)?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have written a bash script that calls several other programs and executes a bunch of commands. I run this script from the terminal. Now I want to kill the script.

Pressing `Ctrl + C` sometimes doesn't cut it, I think because sometimes the script is executing another program, and for some reason the kill signal doesn't work.

However, if I close the terminal window, it kills the script.

Is there something I can do (a keyboard combination), that is analogous to closing the terminal window, without actually closing the terminal window (I don't want to lose command history, current directory, output history, etc.)?

Comment: In such cases I try `Ctrl + z`

Comment: And after `Ctrl + z` run: `kill -9 $(pgrep -f your_script.sh)`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have few options. One is to stop the script (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>), get the PID of the script and send [`SIGKILL`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) to the process group.

When a command is executed in a shell, the process it starts and all its children are part of the same [*process group*](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) (in this case, the foreground process group). To send a signal to all processes in this group, you send it to the process leader. For the [`kill`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/kill.1.html) command, process leader is denoted thus:

```
kill -PID
```

Where `PID` is the process ID of the script.

Example:

Consider a script `test.sh` which launches some processes. Say you ran it in a shell:

```
$ ./test.sh
```

In another terminal,

```
$ pgrep test.sh
17802
$ pstree -ps `!!`
pstree -ps `pgrep test.sh`
init(1)───sshd(1211)───sshd(17312)───sshd(17372)───zsh(17788)───test.sh(17802)─┬─dd(17804)
                                                                               ├─sleep(17805)
                                                                               └─yes(17803)
```

In this case, to send a signal to process group created by `test.sh`, you'd do:

```
kill -INT -17802
```

`-INT` is used to send `SIGINT`, and so this command is the equivalent of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> on the terminal. To send `SIGKILL`:

```
kill -KILL -17802
```

You only need to stop the script if you can't open another terminal. If you can, use `pgrep` to find the PID.

One of the commands that the script launches may be trapping `SIGINT`, which is probably why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is ineffective. However, `SIGKILL` can't be trapped, and it is usually a *last-resort* option. You might want to try `SIGTERM` (`-TERM`) before going for the kill. Neither `SIGKILL` or `SIGTERM` can be set up as a [keyboard shortcut](https://superuser.com/a/417991/334516) the way `SIGINT` is.

All this is moot if your script doesn't contain a shebang line. From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12296783/2072269):

> Usually the parent shell guesses that the script is written for the the same shell (minimal Bourne-like shells run the script with /bin/sh, bash runs it as a bash subprocess) ...

Because of this, when the script is executed, you won't find a process named after script (or a process with the script's name in the command line) and `pgrep` will fail.

Always use a shebang line.

Comment: Is there a keyboard combination for `SIGKILL` or `SIGTERM`?

Comment: @becko No, and you can't set up one: http://superuser.com/a/417991/334516

Comment: `pgrep test.sh` doesn't return the PID for me. I tried a simple test.sh:

`for i in {1..30}; do
 sleep 1
 echo $i
done`
 
While `test.sh` is running, I execute `pgrep test.sh` in another terminal, but nothing is returned. What's wrong?

Comment: @becko how did you run the script? Also try `pgrep -f test.sh`.

Comment: `pgrep -f test.sh` doesn't work either. I run the script with `./test.sh`

Comment: I ran `pstree` and I think I've located my processes. But they have no names. They are all called `bash`, which is why `pgrep` did not find anything. Why? How can I run my `test.sh` with the process name `test.sh`?

Comment: @becko did you put a shebang in your script? (Does it start with `#! /bin/bash`?)

Comment: Nope. The script is this, literally:  


`    for i in {1..30}; do  
     sleep 1  
 echo $i  
    done`

Comment: @becko try with a shebang.

Comment: shebang works! Can you explain? (perhaps as a part of your answer, and I'll accept it)

Comment: @becko A script without a shebang is run a bit differently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12296783/2072269

Answer (score 6):

If you know the processes that are associated with the script you can find their PID using

```
 ps -A
```

and then use the PID number to kill the corresponding processes using

```
 kill -9 PID_Number
```

Comment: That's too complicated. The script spawns several other programs, and these programs also spawn parallel processes. It is very hard to keep track of all these processes. There must be a simpler solution, something analogous to what happens when you close the terminal window.

Comment: Can you try   pkill -P $$

Answer (score 1):

As Harris said you could run `Kill -9 PID_Number` but you could also install the package known as `htop` to have an interactive process browser that makes finding specific processes a lot easier. htop also supports killing processes.